# Convert Dynamic to static url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, lamp

I want a user to type

```
http://localhost/test_url/john
```

instead of

```
http://localhost/test_url/index.php/?user=john
```

I have used many method of editing .htaccess on stackoverflow and other sites but its not working. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 server. There was no ".htaccess" file in /var/www/ by default. I created .htaccess file with 777 permission and modified as mentioned on other pages. How can I check if .htaccess is working or not. And what should I write in .htaccess file to use second url when user types the first url mentioned above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(test_url)/([a-z]+)/?$ /$1/?user=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

1. Use `chmod 644` for `.htaccess`
2. To make sure if your `.htaccess` is enabled try putting same garbage text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?